# can not build my electron react app after installing react-pdf using electron-builder

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, react-pdf

I am building an electron react application. everything was ok and I could build the app binary using electron-builder. but after installing the [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) package the build process is showing error that has something to do with a dependency package called canvas.

package.json

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.0",
        "@monaco-editor/react": "^4.5.1",
        "axios": "^1.4.0",
        "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
        "buffer": "^6.0.3",
        "classnames": "^2.3.2",
        "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
        "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
        "electron-updater": "^6.1.1",
        "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.6.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "react-start": "react-scripts start",
        "react-build": "react-scripts build",
        "react-test": "react-scripts test",
        "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "electron-build": "electron-builder",
        "build-css": "stylus -c src/css/stylus/ --out src/css",
        "watch-css": "npm run build-css && stylus -c -w src/css/stylus/ --out src/css/",
        "build": "npm run build-css && npm run react-build && npm run electron-build",
        "start": "npm run build-css && concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on tcp:127.0.0.1:3000 && electron .\"",
        "dev": "npm run build-css && concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm run react-start\" \"wait-on tcp:127.0.0.1:3000 && electronmon .\""
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^8.2.0",
        "electron": "^25.1.1",
        "electron-builder": "^24.4.0",
        "electronmon": "^2.0.2",
        "stylus": "^0.59.0",
        "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
    }
}
```

build console
[image]

Also tried to run the build command using sudo but got the same error.

please advise

Answer (score 0):

issue solved

first I ran this command `brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg pixman`, found this command at https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

then ran `sudo npm install -g node-gyp`

finally `sudo npm run build` worked